# Publish web page using upnp

Tags: python, upnp

I'm creating an IoT device using a raspberry pi. It is controlled from a web app served from the same RPi. I want to publish that web app using uPnP, to allow any uPnP-compliant device to list it and open it, but I'm unable to achieve it.

The service is coded in python 3, and I tried using the iot-upnp module. I started with the example, but it isn't show neither in VLC in my PC, nor in DMS Explorer in my android phone.

How should I do it?

This is how I'm configuring currently the service: just a test that doesn't export any useful, just to try to see if it works:

```
import upnp

class UPNPAnnouncer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._loop = None
        self._device = upnp.Device({
            'deviceType': 'urn:sadmin-fr:device:demo:1',
            'friendlyName': 'UPnP Test',
            'uuid': '00a56575-78fa-40fe-b107-8f4b5043a2b0',
            'manufacturer': 'BONNET',
            'manufacturerURL': 'http://sadmin.fr'
        })
        self._service = upnp.Service({
            'serviceType': 'sadmin-fr:service:dummy',
            'serviceId': 'sadmin-fr:serviceId:1',
        })
        self._device.addService(self._service)

    def configure(self, loop):
        self._loop = loop
        self._server = upnp.Annoncer(self._device)
        self._server.initLoop(loop)
        loop.create_task(self._send_announces())


    async def _send_announces(self):
        while True:
            print("Notify upnp")
            self._server.notify()
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
```

Comment: I don't think it's as simple as that. Your device advertisement needs to point to a description XML file, which contains a presentation URL which your device can serve using HTTP. PS. you need to import the UPNP library you're using in this snippet, since it's not immediately obvious. I believe you're using IoT-UPnP, right? PPS. As a minimum, you should read this *UPnP-arch-Device Architecture-v1.1.pdf* as an introduction to working with uPnP.

Comment: Yes, it is IoT-UPnP. Sorry for not adding that. The point is that I presumed that the XML was generated automagically by the module using the data passed in the dictionary.

Comment: I am not familiar with this particular library, but I can see that the class *Device* has a property *presentationURL*, so when initialising the device you should be able to include `'presentationURL' : path`, where path is relative to the root of your IoT device.

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, implementing a UPnP device and service is not that simple. It seems that particular library aims to do a ton of the heavy-lifting, but its documentation is very poor, lacking usage examples and how-tos beyond the API docs.

That said, here are some suggestions:

- [UPnP Device Architecture version 2.0](https://openconnectivity.org/upnp-specs/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v2.0-20200417.pdf) is, as mentioned, mandatory reading if you're venturing in UPnP. Also take a look at the [official website](https://openconnectivity.org/developer/specifications/upnp-resources/upnp/), there are tons of documentation there, and their `upnpresources.zip` is extremely helpful.
- Take a look at working examples using this (or another) library. You can start with [upnp-server.py](https://github.com/Flat-Badger-1971/iot-upnp/blob/master/upnp-server.py), a Proof-of-Concept forked from that very library. See if that runs and works, and go on from there.
- Understand all the pieces needed to implement a UPnP server. At the very least you'll need to:

  - Listen on UDP port 1900 for incoming multicast/unicast SSDP `M-SEARCH` messages from clients and *reply* to them. That's the main way your Device/Service will be know to clients. You should also periodically advertise yourself via SSDP `NOTICE` messages.
  - Serve via HTTP (TCP, any port) a description XML file for the root device and one additional XML per Service. Any webserver will do, usually an embedded one from Python's `http.server` or a library, but you could also use Apache/NGinx if you already have one running.
  - Create some HTTP endpoints (2 per Service) and listen for POST requests of SOAP calls made by clients requesting to invoke your Service's Actions and subscribing to Events
  - Reply to the SOAP action calls with their return values, and send events to subscribers when needed using their subscribed HTTP endpoints.

How much of the above is already performed by that library? Use a network sniffer such as `tcpdump` to figure out and fill in the missing parts!

Last but not the least, be aware that clients might only list Devices supporting the Services they're interested in: VLC and Smart TVs only cares about Media Servers, and most likely ignores Internet Gateway Devices (Home Routers), and so on. For testing you'll need a general UPnP client scanner / explorer that lists *all* devices and services on your network